# Geopandas conda install UnsatisfiableError glibc

Tags: python, conda, geopandas, anaconda3

This is a new anaconda3 installation on centos 7.9 and geopandas is not getting installed due to UnsatisfiableError.

$ conda --version is conda 4.13.0

```
$conda install geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.                                                                                                                                              failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.17
```

Any thoughts how to fix install geopandas?

Comment: Have you tried a fresh env `conda create -n geopandasEnv geopandas`?

Comment: Agree fresh conda env without other anaconda packages will install geopandas. But here I was trying to install geopandas into the (base) anaconda env with all other 200 anaconda packages that are pre-installed. Looks like geopandas will not install due to conflicts with other anaconda packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here, same version of conda (4.13.0).
I re-installed anaconda from the latest available script (2022.05), same issue.
I resolved the problem by installing geopandas using

```
pip install geopandas
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that pip install will not check dependencies like conda install does and eventually in future your conda install of any other packages will stop working. It will just keep looping trying to find dependencies and your conda environment will become unusable so you will need to create a new conda environment to install new packages. So better not to use conda install and pip install together in the same conda environment and stick to conda install only.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a temporary solution but I really needed it to be functional.